# Stuck trying to copy files to a new directory under specific guidelines

Tags: linux, find, cp

I'm trying to copy all files from a folder that start with a capital letter into another folder.

So far i've used the find command to actually find the files

```
find /examplefolder -type f -name "[[:upper:]]*"
```

and i'm able to find them no problem

I tried to just replace the find `command` with `cp` and that does not work then i tried to pipe into the `cp` command and I failed yet again

Comment: find /examplefolder -type f -name "[[:upper:]]*" -exec cp {} /my/new/shiny/folder/ \;

Answer (score 0):

Use the -exec option for find

```
find /examplefolder -type f -name "[[:upper:]]*" -exec cp {} /my/new/shiny/folder/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by piping in to cp with xargs and the -I argument

find /examplefolder -type f -name "[[:upper:]]*" | xargs -I % cp % /copied_directory